# Mysql get insert time/date without having date/time field

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which has an auto increment id field(id), videoid(int) and userid(int). The site is live now. I forgot to put a date/time field there. now there are some data here. Is it possible to get the insert time for all the existing data?

I have another table which gets reset every week by a cron job. Something wrong happened last week and now I badly need those data. Is there any option by which I can get any kind of backup from a certain date? Does mysql has auto backup or something like that?

Comment: Hosting provider keeps backup of past few day.You should contact provider.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the binary log, you can get the insert statements by using `mysqlbinlog`. Read more about it in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlbinlog.html).

> The output from mysqlbinlog can be re-executed (for example, by using it as input to mysql) to redo the statements in the log. This is useful for recovery operations after a server crash.